# AngularJS Defer.promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, persistence, promise, deferred

I'm developing an application using **AngularJS**  & **PersistenceJS**.

I'm getting trouble dealing with Asynchronous calls as the

**Controller** :

```
cars.controller('CrashWidgetOneCtrl',function($scope, $location, $routeParams, CrashServices){  
    if($routeParams.crashId){
        $scope.data = {};
        console.log("CrashID: "+$routeParams.crashId);
        crashId = $routeParams.crashId; 
        alert(1);//Works

        CrashServices.getCrashDetails($scope, crashId).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            alert(2);//Never Fires
        });    
    alert(3);//Gets executed
    }else{
        console.log("N");
    }   

});
```

**Services** :

```
cars.factory('CrashServices', function($http, $location, $q, CommonServices,$rootScope, $timeout){
    return{
        getCrashDetails:function($scope, crashId){
        var deferred = $q.defer();          
        // Get user details if any
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            var crashInfoTable = App.CrashInfoTable.all();
            alert(4);
            crashInfoTable.list(null, function (results) { 
                alert(5);//This also doesn't work
                deferred.resolve();
            }); 
        });
        return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Note: I am using PersistenceJS.

Comment: i guess App.CrashInfoTable.all() is also an asynchronous call. What is the resturn type? Also a promise?

Comment: If crashInfoTable's callback isn't called then promise is not resolved. So Defer.promise does work as expected. It doesn't fire success callback function till resolved. Maybe there's something wrong with model? check out this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/persistencejs/eIfuqyXK09E

Comment: @michael:  App.CrashInfoTable.all() is not asynchronous.. Im not sure about the return type... How can i know that?

Comment: @RoyMJ instead of alter(4) you should do console.log(crashInfoTable);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you need the scope.apply.
This seemed to work for me:

```
getCrashDetails:function($scope, crashId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();          
    // Get user details if any
    App.CrashInfoTable.all().list(null, function(results) { 
        deferred.resolve(results);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Yep.. This is indeed what i ended up doing.. This was way back..;)... Thanks though.. Appreciate it..

Comment: ...Like a phoenix from the ashes ;) Thought it might help someone else who had the same problem.